# How to move Rails routes into a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need to define the same routes multiple places in my `routes.rb` file. I've placed it inside a `my_routes` method, but I don't like having methods directly in my routes file.

What would be the proper way to do this?

Here is my current approach:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  def my_routes
    get ":_controller" => "my_controller#index"
    ...
  end

  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    my_routes
  end

  my_routes
end
```

I realize that I could simply replace `":locale"` with `(":locale")` in the above example to avoid having to reference `my_routes` twice, but that's not the point of my question. My question is how to move routes definitions into a method.

Comment: Use [concerns](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use concerns in this case.
Something like that:

```
concern :my_routes do
  get ":_controller" => "my_controller#index"
end

scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  concerns :my_routes
end

concerns :my_routes
```